# How to parse markdown within multiple divs

Tags: html, jekyll, bootstrap-4

I am using Jekyll together with bootstrap-4 and try to have code rendered within a accordion view but i can't get jekyll to render the markdown within the divs.

I tried to add the `markdown="1"` flag to all "upper" divs but it's not parsing it.

Simple Example whish i would love to see working:

````html
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        ## first card with markdown ```swift let code: bool = true ```
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Some content within the second card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
````

Question: How to I dell jekyll to render something within multiple divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `markdownify` to convert a Markdown-formatted string into HTML.

```
{{ page.excerpt | markdownify }}
```

or simply pass the output to the markdownify

```
{{ "# foo bar" | markdownify }}
```

Or load your markdown file in your HTML page:

- Create a markdown formatted file (e.g. `foo.md`)

  - Put your markdown's formatted text on it
- load `foo.md` file in you page:

> ```
> <div class="card-body">
> ```

```
{% capture foo_bar %}{% include foo.md %}{% endcapture %}  
{{ foo_bar | markdownify }}
```

> ```
> </div>
> ```

Comment: I got a markdown file where i want to add stuff like this. I recognized that i can simply include html within the markdown and itll presented properly.

It looks like i have to create a html template to include things within a accordion? Id like to be able to have multiple accordions included within one "markdown rendered" website.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. I got a template where the Markdown is included and markdownified. I'd like to be able to create accordions within that markdown file which is displayed within the whole context.

Comment: No, it is not mandatory to always use markdown files, I you can pass markdown formatted text directly to the markdownify

Comment: I tried having `{{ "#foo bar" | markdownify }}` within that html block but it wont get translated to html.

Comment: @BennX sorry, put a `space` character after `#`

Comment: I could have known that. Including also does work. Is there a way to have a multiline within the `{{ "# foo bar" | markdownify }}` ? So its all at one spot..

Comment: yes you can, but be careful about spaces and indents. I recommend to use usual method, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Just started with Jekyll sites and I think need some more basic understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In ***_config.yml*** :

```
kramdown:
  # instruct kramdown to parse inside html block elements
  # like p, header, lists, ...
  parse_block_html: true
```